# Is there a way to see how far a task has gotten?

Tags: google-earth-engine, taskmanager

The current task (creating a density map of buildings in urban areas in Africa) has been running for nearly 5 days, is there a way of working out how long it might take?

```
var buildings = ee.FeatureCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings/v1/polygons').filterBounds(high_density_clusters)

var countImg = buildings//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
.reduceToImage({
    properties: [],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  })
  //.reproject('epsg:4326',null, 1000);
  
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: countImg,
  description: 'Density_map',
  assetId: 'Density_map',
  scale: 1000,
  region: high_density_clusters
});
```

Imports needed are:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[29.06958022555639, -25.806207950348288],
          [29.06958022555639, -25.890248876263332],
          [29.16021743258764, -25.890248876263332],
          [29.16021743258764, -25.806207950348288]]], null, false),
    high_density_clusters = ee.FeatureCollection("users/bucklandtheresa/high_density_clusters");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to see how far it's gotten, however if the task fails, Earth Engine will retry it up to 5 times (depending on why it failed).

If it's still on attempt #1, you've still got a good chance of it finishing.
If you're on try #2 or more, there's a diminishing chance that it will ever successfully finish.

If your high_density_clusters geometry is really complex, then there's a good chance that's the problem, since the whole geometry has to be reprojected for every tile.  You could try using a simpler version of that to speed things up.  (But wait until it fails at least once, just in case it might still succeed).

Comment: It computationally timed out after 6 days! Could I reduce complexity by using bounding rectangles? I'm trying that and it's still taking considerable time even for a relatively small country (like Lesotho). For context, I've made high_density_clusters public here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/bucklandtheresa/high_density_clusters and the code with bounding rectangles can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/27021e0ac3fc071c8bbb388e9ac70f7b

Comment: I meant, you should use a simplified version of the country.  ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").  This script, with a hand-drawn region, finished in 4 minutes: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d12cc3e9f1185d47908faccb937856b2

Comment: That now works for most countries! But there are memory problems for some (e.g. Egypt, Ghana, Angola). When I break it down into smaller regions, it seems like large cities on the coastline are giving problems (e.g. Accra, Luanda), but since I use bounding rectangles around urban areas I'm not sure why: https://code.earthengine.google.com/19a2edf75022d9b5c3409f1dcee420b1

Comment: I have also asked the above question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409577/why-do-i-get-memory-problems-reducing-over-specific-regions