# Why do I get memory problems reducing over specific regions?

Tags: google-earth-engine, memory

The code below works for most countries but there are memory problems for some (e.g. Egypt, Ghana, Angola), even though these countries do not have a bigger population or land area than some countries where it works (e.g. South Africa). When I break the area (of the countries where the code fails) down into smaller regions, it seems like large cities on the coastline are giving problems (e.g. Accra, Luanda), but since I use bounding rectangles around urban areas I'm not sure why (e.g. it doesn't seem to be because of complex shapes).

```
var country = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Angola'))
  
var BoundingRectangles = function(feature) {
  feature = feature.geometry().bounds();
  return feature
};

high_density_clusters = high_density_clusters.map(BoundingRectangles)
Map.addLayer(high_density_clusters)


var union = high_density_clusters.filterBounds(country)
union = union.union(100)
Map.addLayer(union, {}, 'union')

var buildings = ee.FeatureCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings/v1/polygons').filterBounds(country)

var countImg = buildings//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
.reduceToImage({
    properties: [],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  })
  //.reproject('epsg:4326',null, 1000);
  
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: countImg,
  description: 'union',
  assetId: 'union',
  scale: 1000,
  region: union
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a code where the variable high_density_clusters is available? Otherwise the code cannot be tested.

Comment: Here's the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/bucklandtheresa/high_density_clusters

Comment: can you show an example where you code actually breaks or that your problem is highlighted? My first guess would be that your buildings are way too complex features (e.g. a lot of vertices in your union output) to apply a reduce to image on.

Comment: Here is an example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b18e1fc854c4d399c17a72bfe595c4ac?noload=1

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you are doing

```
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: countImg,
  description: 'union',
  assetId: 'union',
  scale: 1000,
  region: union
});
```

The area of `union` covers the entire globe (you can easily verify this by adding countImg to the map with `Map.addLayer(countImg);`). Thus you are exporting a very large image, even if most of it is made up of zeroes. You should replace `region: union` with `region: country`.

Comment: The area of union is smaller than the area of country because of the line `var union = high_density_clusters.filterBounds(country)` - so I think it must be something else! I'm assuming it'll be something that's specific to some regions and not others, because it works well for some areas (e.g. Lesotho, South Africa).

Comment: No. It doesn't matter that you filter bounds, the image you are exporting covers the entire globe. Like I said, you can see for yourself by adding countImg to the map.